How to force which degenerate orbital is occupied during the HF optimization process on Gaussian09?
I am currently running a RHF calculation on a singlet fragment of the central atom in a $D_{2h}$ symmetric linear molecule contained in the $z$-axis (both the $x$- and $y$-axes are degenerate). The calculation runs fine and converges with no issue with the current basis set; however, the issue I am running into is more of a connivence issue.
The central atom fragment calculation populates the $p_{x}$ and $p_{z}$ fragment orbitals (FOs) as occupied degenerate orbitals (HOMO/HOMO-1), and the $p_{y}$ orbital as an unoccupied orbital (LUMO). When I run a MPA on the whole molecule with respect to the fragments, degenerate molecular orbitals (MOs) in the $x$- and $y$-axes contain slightly different contributions from $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ FOs on the central atom fragment since the original fragment calculation for the central atom treated the $p_{x}$ and $p_{z}$ FOs rather than $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ FOs as degenerate.
Basically my question is: How would I be able to force my central atom fragment calculation to treat $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ as occupied degenerate orbitals and $p_{z}$ as an unoccupied orbital.
I am currently using Gaussian09 for my calculation.
Thank you very much for the help in advanced.
